# Swift 3.0 map seems to iterate through 1 more loop

Tags: swift, function, swift-playground

Let's consider following image [image]

I am using map in two different ways. First one say it iterate 6 times. Which is of course ok since we have array of  size 6. Next sample on map shows it iterate 7 times which I don't know why.

But the result showing is same.  Now I was just wondering what's difference  between two.

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
var newArr1 = numArr.map{$0 * 2}
```

may be executed 7 times, but the iteration over array members is only executed 6 times. Try rewriting the statement like this:

```
var newArr1 = numArr.map {
    $0 * 2
}
```

You'll see the line `$0 * 2` is only executed 6 times

Comment: yes you are correct